# Can't correct deploy infopath 2010 form with formcode

Tags: deployment, workflow, sharepoint-2010, infopath, publishing

I'm new in Infopath developing, please help. :(

So I'm developing work-flow with custom task edit form.

I designed infopath form CustomApprovalForm.xsn in Infopath Designer 2010 and then I published this form to Workflow project in Module folder which named Form(ApproveWF/Form/).

Then I configured all needed properties for correct deploying. After deploying all works ok and form appears as it should be.

But when I come back to Infopath designer 2010 and add some formcode to CustomApproval.xsn and then I press quick publish to Module folder which I use above and then I deploy the workflow to SP server.

After this  the form doesn't appear.

In logs I saw exception:

> "Solution deserialization failed with unhandled exception
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\Template\Features\ApproveWF_Feature1\CustomApprovalForm.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified...."

I suppose, that I'm not correct making publishing infopath form with code behind.

How to correct do publishing infopath 2010 form with code behind to my ApproveWF project which then deploy to SP server?

Where should I place the CustomApproval.dll?

Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

I have to add new item to Workflow project which named Empty Element. And then I've added dll of xsn CustomForm to it. And then I've deployed this dll with xsn form like feature to sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, but I'll have to double-check, that what happened is that you did a full publish first with no code behind the form - this registered the manifest, which did not include a reference to a .dll, since there wasn't one.

You then added code, which gets compiled into a dll, listed in the manifest for the form.

I *think* when you do a quick-publish, the form files are copied up to the server, but the manifest isn't re-registered. So the form xml/xsl will have calls to the dll, but the manifest won't know where to find it, since it wasn't updated.

tl;dr: when you publish a form then add code to it, you have to run a full publishing cycle again to update the installed manifest.

Post a follow-up if this doesn't work.